Unable to open .pem file in MacOs
When I'm trying to set up EC2 instance on AWS, I'm unable to open the password certificate after downloading on macOs. It says "error occurred.unable to import an item". How to fix this? The error occurs after downloading the password keychain after creating server on aws.


There is no need to 'open' a .pem file. There is no app that would use it.
Instead, reference the file when using the SSH command, like this:
ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@1.2.3.4

If you receive an error about permissions, you can change permissions with:
chmod 400 key.pem

